# 8051 Flash Memory not Writing to chip

Tags: c, flash, memory, 8051, flash-memory

I am using the 8051 microcontroller to read, write, and erase from flash memory.
Attached are the waveform for programming operations[image: Waveform for Programming operations]

And below is the code that I have written in order to recreate the waveform in order to write data into the chip:

```
void quick_write_op(void)
{
    unsigned char i;

    char SFRPAGE_SAVE=SFRPAGE;
    SFRPAGE=CONFIG_PAGE;

    //test=1;
    Vpp_en=0; //8 volts is supplied to the board. Read/Write operations allowed

    //Wait at least 1us between Vpp high and CSn low
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){}

    //Set-Up program command
    P5=0x40;CSn=0;WEn=0;WEn=1;CSn=1;

    //Program Command (Latch Address & Data)
    P5=data_byte;CSn=0;WEn=0;WEn=1;CSn=1;

    //Wait at least 10us for programming
    for(i=0;i<23;i++){}

    //Program Verify Command
    P5=0xC0;CSn=0;WEn=0;WEn=1;CSn=1;

    //Wait at least 6us for program verify
    for(i=0;i<17;i++){}

    //Program Verification
    P5MDOUT=0x00; //Configured pins to open-drain
    CSn=0;OEn=0;
    OEn=1;CSn=1;

    //Resets the command register 
    P5MDOUT=0xFF;
    P5=0x00;CSn=0;WEn=0;WEn=1;CSn=1;

    Vpp_en=1; //8 volts is now removed
    //test=0;

    SFRPAGE=SFRPAGE_SAVE;
}
```

I am going to assume that this code is fairly simple to follow seeing that there is a picture to go along with it detailing what I should do. If for some reason that it is hard to follow, then please let me know and I will clarify by adding code, images, etc.

I don't believe that there is a timing issue anywhere as I have checked that with a logic analyzer. When I invoke the write command, I want to write a `0x55` to address `0x00000`, I should expect to see a `0x55` at address `0x00000`. Instead, I am reading back an empty address, `0xFF`. Therefore being forever stuck in the `WRITE_LOOP` until the right data is read in. Of course I may be blinded by my own bias so if I could get extra pairs of eyes on this and advice then I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you all.

Comment: Timing diagram shows 12V on Vpp not 8V per your comment. Does your Vpp circuitry really raise the Vpp voltage to 12V or 8V in less than a microsecond? Not obvious how you are outputting the address to the flash.

Comment: Can you see the assembly?  Is there a chance that your empty loops are being optimized out?

Comment: What is the point of `while(write_read!=data_byte)` as neither value changes in the loop?  Is `RFLAG` `volatile`?

Comment: @chux Write_read is read from p5 just above that line. However that also leaves OEn at 0 which doesn't seem correct, should reassert it to 1

Comment: @barny Neither `write_read` nor `data_byte` change  in `while(write_read!=data_byte)
    {
        if(RFLAG==1){break;}
        goto WRITE_LOOP;
    }`

Comment: The goto WRITE_LOOP makes the code loop back and modify write_read. Horrible.

Comment: @barny Ah yes, a `goto`...  Still looks like weird that `while(write_read!=data_byte)` loop

Comment: Nasty code organisation - suggest getting rid of WRITE_LOOP label and the corresponding goto, make WRITE_LOOP into a while (true) and break out if the data reads back correct or RFLAG is 1. And you *MUST* set OEn and CSn back to 1 after reading P5. How hard can it be, given you have a picture as well as the code?

Comment: @barny I have talked to one of the design engineers and they modified the chip in order to recognize `8V` as a sufficient supply. Since the posting of the question I have taken out the `goto` statement. Originally I had it in there in order to keep checking `P5` until it matched the value in the `data_byte` variable but I agree. The placement of the `goto` loop could be improved if were to put it back in the code.

Comment: Yes just get rid of the goto, not needed at all. And get a scope on the Vpp line, make sure it is actually rising to whatever voltage the chip needs to tell it to program just as quickly as you are expecting. If in doubt make the delays a lot longer, doesn't do any harm

Comment: @barny also, I did set them back to 1. After the `while loop` which I took out now.

Comment: Well clearly update your question, then. No crystal balls.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! One last thought, I am about 6 months new to coding so any organizational tips would be appreciated as well.